# What do I call the subject and object of a subscription?

Tags: single-word-requests

Alice is subscribed to Bob's posts.

Alice is a ____?

Bob is a ____?

---

And also a similar question:

Charlie follows David on Twitter.

Charlie is a *follower*.

David is a ____?

Comment: subscriber, provider

Comment: Alice is a subscriber or benefactor and Bob is a payee or beneficiary. Charlie is a follower and David is a followee.

Comment: Is there any word for Bob derived from "subscribe"?

Comment: It seems there is no such a word. "Subscriber" is the agent noun of the verb "subscribe", in this context meaning, "contribute money to" or "become a regular buyer of a publication". See the etymology here:http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=subscribe

Comment: David and Bob are posters.  They post to their blogs or twitter feeds.

Comment: It used to be *subscriber/publisher*. I don't know about Twitter and such - I tend towards *poster* too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"David is a **followee**" -- [ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/followee)

> (noun)
>
> 1. a person who is being tracked on a social media website or application.
>    *"some people were upset that followers and followees are displayed on your public profile page"*
> 2. a person who is being followed.
>    *"tailgaters are fools—if an accident happens, the follower gets the blame, not the followee"*

Answer (score 0):

> David is a ***fount*** of wit.

The idea is to explain why he's worthy of being followed.

> A source of a desirable quality or commodity.
>
> *‘our courier was a fount of knowledge’*
>
> <sub>[Oxford Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/fount)</sub>

Comment: Being a fount of wit does not necessarily mean you are followed. Conversely, one can be a blithering idiot and have thousands of followers. IOW, this term describes a quality of a single person, not their role in a relationship as requested.

Comment: @michael.hor257k I don't disagree. I used the more idiomatic usage in my answer, but I think *fount* can be used standalone, like HBO is a *network*.

Comment: I don't think you can have a network without affiliates. But we are digressing.